# Path error with PHP include();

Tags: php, php4

While I am developing my site I have it hosted on my current site in a folder. I'm not very good with levels, but this is how I set it up. In the top of my body I have:

```
<?php include('../includes/menu.php'); ?>
```

I have my page.php in /learn/ and the classes in /learn/includes
Should i do ../../ ?

PS: I'm making my first CMS

Comment: Did you make sure the path is correct in needing to go up one?

Comment: You should define a home directory variable and have all your includes path follow it. Now you won't be restricted in which subdivision your PHP files need to be in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you would just need:

```
include('includes/menu.php');
```

Comment: Thank you. That was the first thing I did, but I did include('/includes/menu.php');

Thank you!

Comment: @JonasRothmannHjalager Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the tick next to the answer you choose!

Comment: It says: You can't accept an answer in 6 minutes
I just joined the site, can it be something with that?

Comment: Can I ask for another question in here or would I have to start another question?

Comment: I would start a new question unless it involves includes

Comment: I have another includes, which includes the output of tinymce. It's called content.php Right now I only have 1 comment in it. That comment doesn't show up in the source. Is it cache or what is it?

Comment: Turned out to be a cache issue:)

Answer (score 1):

If the `includes` directory is inside the `learn` directory then you would use:

```
<?php include('./includes/menu.php'); ?>
```

or

```
<?php include('includes/menu.php'); ?>
```